# how objects interacts with each other in java using methods?

Tags: java, object, methods, interaction

I am learning java and can do pretty much coding myself without any issues. But I have been always reading in the books - In java, objects interact with each other by invoking methods of other objects?

I am unsure if I got that clearly. Example is like, a `Robot` class which has methods like `moveForward()`, `comeToBase()`,`increaseSpeed()` etc. Now if there are two robot objects, then how will they interact with each other to avoid clash? I can understand very well that each robot object can invoke its own methods independently and run independently but how does the interaction between the object happens? Can someone explain based on the above example?

Comment: What interaction are you talking about?

Comment: You can invoke the methods of any object you have a refence to. If you wanted to robots to be aware of each other you would have to pass them references to each other. More usually a higher object would manage both (like a physics engine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects typically talk to one another via use of references. For example:

```
class Robot {
    private String m_name;

    public void SetName(String name) {
       m_name = name;
    }

    public String GetName() {
       return m_name;
    }

    public void TalkTo(Robot robot, String speech){
        console.writeline(robot.GetName + " says " + speech " to you.");
    }
}

void MyMethod() {
    Robot robotOne = new Robot();  // variable robotOne contains a reference to a robot
    Robot robotTwo = new Robot();  // variable robotTwo contains a reference to another robot
    robotTwo.SetName("Robert");

    // the first robot says hi to the second
    robotOne.TalkTo(robotTwo, "hello");

   // output
   // Robert says hello to you
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take

> In java, objects interact with each other by invoking methods of other objects

to mean that the RobotFleet Object contains many Robot objects and can manipulate them through the methods on the Robot object.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Richard Tingle is right - for two Robot objects to react with one another, it makes sense for there to be a higher level class to control them both, and deal with moving them, what to do if they will collide, increasing speed based on certain conditions, etc.

You'd probably have a higher level class with a main loop that upon each loop calls methods that deal with user inputs, physical timings, object behaviors, object collisions, rendering objects, and so on, until the whole scenario ends and control is passed to another part of your code. So this class with the main loop could invoke a method that iterates through all Robot objects, and calls certain methods on the Robot objects to determine how to respond based on the current physically modeled environment.

A similar level of class would be responsible for creating and initialising the Robot objects, and passing control through your system to manage the whole program. Everything you model in Java can be regarded as an Object, even higher level modelling such as game initialisation and game flow management.

For a very basic example:

```
public class Game {

    private List<Robot> robots = new ArrayList<Robot>();
    private boolean GameEnded = false;

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        initiliaseGame();
        startGameLoop();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void initialiseGame() {
        Robot robot1 = new Robot();
        robots.add(robot1);
        Robot robot2 = new Robot();
        robots.add(robot2);
    }

    private void StartGameLoop() {
        while (!gameEnded) {
            /* would need time control logic here for more manageable and consistent simulation */
            updateRobots(); // could check for collisions between other Robots here
            drawRobots();
        }
    }

    private updateRobots() {
        for (Robot robot : robots) {
            robot.update(); // do each robots behaviour (physics, decisions, etc)
        }
    }

    private drawRobots() {
        for (Robot robot : robots) {
            robot.draw(); // draw each robot
        }
    }
}
```